# Optionals with JPA and Spaghetti code in Springboot API

Tags: java, api, hibernate, jpa

I have a few questions about the use of optionals in an API that I am working on.

1. First, I am using in my native queries (in my JPA repositories) as return optionals.
   It's okay to use them like this?
2. Also I have a service that checks if one of my entity exits by its id if not it throws a custom exception. What I don't understand is the service can return the Object type, but the JPA query definition is: Optional findById(ID id) ???

```
    public BasicTvShowInfo getBasicTvShowInfoById (Integer idTvShow) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        return basicTvShowInfoRepository.findById(idTvShow).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(
                "The tv show with the id : " + idTvShow + " was not found."));
    }
```

3. Finally, I have a validation when I want to post an entity call TvShowReminder. This entity is declared as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tv_show_reminder")
public class TvShowReminder {

    // Attributes
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id_tv_show_reminder")
    private Integer idTvShowReminder;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_user")
    @NotNull(message = "Provide user {idUser}")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name= "id_basic_tv_show_info")
    private BasicTvShowInfo basicTvShowInfo;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name= "id_tv_show_created_by_user")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private UserTvShow userTvShow;

    private Boolean completed;

    @Column(name = "current_season")
    private Integer currentSeason;

    @Column(name = "current_episode")
    private Integer currentEpisode;

    @Column(name = "personal_rating")
    private Integer personalRating;
```

It has two nested entities, that can be nullable. The BasicTvShowInfo and UserTvShow.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "basic_tv_show_info")

public class BasicTvShowInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_basic_tv_show_info")
    @NotNull(message = "Provide id (Integer)")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "original_name")
    @JsonProperty("original_name")
    @NotNull(message = "Provide original_name (String)")
    private String originalName;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tv_show_created_by_user")
public class UserTvShow {

    // Attributes
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_tv_show_created_by_user")
    private Integer idTvShowCreatedByUser;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name= "id_user")
    @NotNull(message = "Provide user {idUser}")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "name_tv_show")
    @NotNull(message = "Provide nameTvShow (String)")
    private String nameTvShow;

    private String genre;

    @Column(name = "production_company")
    private String productionCompany;
}
```

I have a validation method in the service that checks:

1. if both the BasicTvShowInfo and UserTvShow are null.
2. if both objects (BasicTvShowInfo and UserTvShow) have an id.
3. if the logged user already has a reminder with the BasicTvShowInfo id provided.
4. if the logged user already has a reminder with the UserTvShow id provided.

In all these cases I throw exceptions.

How can I refactor this service method which is working perfectly but I want to write it more elegantly? I really don't like to use so many if-elseif-else and nested ifs. It gets really hard to follow the code.

This is the method:

```
    private void validateExistenceOfTvShowReminder(TvShowReminder tvShowReminder) throws ResourceAlreadyExistsException, BusinessLogicValidationFailure, ResourceNotFoundException {
        Optional<TvShowReminder> tvShowReminderOptional = Optional.empty();
        String messageError = null;

        // If both the basic tv show info object and user tv show object ARE PRESENT -> exception
        // If the basic tv show info object id already exists in the reminders table -> exception
        // If the user tv show info object id already exists in the reminders table -> exception
        // If both are null -> exception.

        if(tvShowReminder.getBasicTvShowInfo() != null && tvShowReminder.getUserTvShow() != null){

            if(tvShowReminder.getBasicTvShowInfo().getId() != null && tvShowReminder.getUserTvShow().getIdTvShowCreatedByUser() != null)
                throw new BusinessLogicValidationFailure("You cant have a reminder that point to a tv show from the system and to a tv show created by the user");

        } else if(tvShowReminder.getBasicTvShowInfo() != null){

            if(tvShowReminder.getBasicTvShowInfo().getId() != null) {
                tvShowReminderOptional = tvShowReminderRepository.findByUserIdAndTvShowId(tvShowReminder.getUser().getIdUser(), tvShowReminder.getBasicTvShowInfo().getId());
                messageError = "User already created a tv show reminder with the basicTvShowInfo id : " + tvShowReminder.getBasicTvShowInfo().getId();
            }

        } else if (tvShowReminder.getUserTvShow() != null){

            if(tvShowReminder.getUserTvShow().getIdTvShowCreatedByUser() != null) {

                // Validate if the user tv show of the reminder actually belongs to the logged user.
                if(Optional.ofNullable(userTvShowService.getUserTvShow(tvShowReminder.getUser().getIdUser(), tvShowReminder.getUserTvShow().getIdTvShowCreatedByUser())).isPresent()) {

                    tvShowReminderOptional = tvShowReminderRepository.findByUserIdAndTvShowCreatedByUserId(tvShowReminder.getUser().getIdUser(), tvShowReminder.getUserTvShow().getIdTvShowCreatedByUser());
                    messageError = "User already created a tv show reminder with a userTvShow id : " + tvShowReminder.getUserTvShow().getIdTvShowCreatedByUser();
                }
            }

        } else {
            messageError = "To create a tv show reminder you have to provided a basicTvShowInfo id OR a userTvShow id";
            throw new BusinessLogicValidationFailure(messageError);
        }

        // Each query findByUserIdAndTvShowId and findByUserIdAndTvShowCreatedByUserId return an optional with the tv show or an empty optional.
        // This method will return true if there is a tv show present in the optional OR returns false if is an empty optional (with null value).
        if(tvShowReminderOptional.isPresent()){
            throw new ResourceAlreadyExistsException(messageError);
        }
    }

// Repository if it is of any help is:

@Repository
public interface TvShowReminderRepository extends JpaRepository<TvShowReminder, Integer> {
    Page<TvShowReminder> findByUser_IdUser(Pageable pageable, Integer idUser);
    List<TvShowReminder> findByUser_IdUser(Integer idUser);

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tv_show_reminder WHERE id_user = ?1 and id_basic_tv_show_info = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<TvShowReminder> findByUserIdAndTvShowId(Integer idUser, Integer idBasicTvShowInfo);

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tv_show_reminder WHERE id_user = ?1 and id_tv_show_created_by_user = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<TvShowReminder> findByUserIdAndTvShowCreatedByUserId(Integer idUser, Integer idTvShowCreatedByUser);

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tv_show_reminder WHERE id_user = ?1 and id_tv_show_reminder = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<TvShowReminder> findByIdTvShowReminderAndUserId(Integer idUser, Integer idTvShowReminder);
}
```

Sorry for the long post, thank you in advance, if anyone can help me or guide me to the right approach I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. First, I am using in my native queries (in my JPA repositories) as return optionals. It's okay to use them like this?

I don't see why it wouldn't be ok.

> 2. Also I have a service that checks if one of my entity exits by its id if not it throws a custom exception. What I don't understand is the service can return the Object type, but the JPA query definition is: Optional findById(ID id) ???

This is fine as well. Spring Data just didn't want to impose the cost of throwing an exception every time an object wasn't found which is why they use the optional approach. You can do whatever you want with that.

> 3. Finally, I have a validation when I want to post an entity call TvShowReminder. This entity is declared as:

To refactor validation into more readable form, I would recommend you look into the Jakarta/Java EE Validation API, also called Bean Validation API: https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation